# Vuejs Model Binding Error

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, model-binding, vue-component

I have been working on vuejs for 5 months now its a great frame work but currently i am having this issue of model binding with my input.. I was trying to add a language object to my languages array on run time but when i clear my language object after adding to the languages array it also clears it from the array.. this is my input field

This is my jsfiddle

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/abdur_rehman26/5sk4dnqg/
```

if i uncomment last two lines i am facing the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

`var language = this.newLanguage` - you pass a reference to the object. Then, when binding values change, your list items change too.

Solution: create a new cloned object to be pushed into an array:

`var language = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.newLanguage))`

Then it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/f88jxyw7/

Comment: thanks man.. althoguh i found another way of doing it but yours is cleaner.. cheers